# Render all sprites only within the tilemap

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a tilemap/ multiple tilemaps in the Scene and I want every sprite only to be rendered within the tilemap(s). If there is a gameobject with a sprite outside the map(s), it shouldn't be rendered. How can I achieve this?

I've considered using Sprite Masks, however, there's no way to convert all the tilemaps into one sprite/mask.

Comment: Just use a detect code of whether a sprite exists in the tile map (Using 2D collisions would be an easy way), then just disable the sprite renderer

Comment: Well, this should be quite a waste since I would have to attach the script to every gameobject with sprites. This also somewhat makes it prone to errors (for ex. forgetting to attach this script to a sprite).

Comment: Attach the script to some empty game object, create a list of game objects and use GameObject.Find to attach all the sprites to it. Then loop through and apply the logic I've explained above.

Comment: Well, this could work. I'm going to try it.